# Caching a resource in Varnish-Cache after specific number of requests

Tags: nginx, caching, varnish, varnish-vcl

Is there any functionality like [proxy_cache_min_uses](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_min_uses) of Nginx in the [Varnish-Cache](http://varnish-cache.org/) that caches a resource after specific number of requests to that resource?
Here is some similar solution in [Varnish-Cache plus](https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/) (based on [slimhazard](https://github.com/slimhazard)'s comment on [this issue](https://github.com/varnishcache/varnish-cache/issues/3150)):

```
import vsthrottle;

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/min/use/me" && vsthrottle.is_denied(req.url, 50, 2h, 1h) {
        # If the URL was requested more than 50 times during the last two hours,
        # then go to cache lookup for the next hour.
        return (hash);
    }
    else {
        # Otherwise bypass the cache
        return (pass);
    }
}
```

Is there any similar solution that could be used in Varnish-Cache itself?

Comment: You could keep count of the requests on the backend - and if they go over the limit, set a header value which forces Varnish to cache the response.

Answer (score 2):

Not in Varnish Cache core in itself, but you can achieve this with a VMOD, like [this counter VMOD](https://github.com/xcir/libvmod-xcounter).

It will allow you to increment some counter for a number of times a resource was requested and then check its value and apply caching logic required.